# What is the use of ES6 Promise then() fulfillment handler returning a value?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

It is said that [inside a `.then()` fulfillment handler, if a value `v1` (a non promise object) is returned, then the promise as returned by `then()` will be a resolved promise, with the resolved value `v1`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Return_value).

But what use is this feature?  If we immediately resolve this promise, we may as well write code directly underneath inside this `then()` fulfillment handler.

Example:

```
myPromise.then(function(someV) {
  // ...
  return v1;
}).then(function(v) {
  // some code
```

That is, we may as well move `// some code` into the first fulfillment handler.

(I thought the usual use case is to return a `new Promise()` so that we can chain up promises.)

Comment: Can you please cite the specific sentence where it says that "*the promise as returned by `then()` will be a resolved promise*"? All I can find on that MDN page are mentions like "*the promise returned by `then` gets resolved*" (without direct temporal qualification). The returned promise is always pending.

Comment: @Bergi it is the first item in that list: "returns a value, the promise returned by then gets resolved with the returned value as its value."

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question. You were asking about moving the code into the *next* `then` handler, not about moving it underneath (and outside) the `then` handler in case the promise is resolved synchronously (which it never is).

Comment: There probably aren't many cases where you would write code like this, i.e. you'd always move "`// some code`" into the first handler. But that a promise chain eventually has to return a non-promise value is rather obvious, so I'm a bit lost where you're lost here.

Answer (score 1):

That's a decent question. In other "monadic constructs" there are two functions for this (one for mapping and the other for mapping for a promise) but sometime in 2013 it was decided not to do the same thing in JavaScript and allow returning a value.

This makes sense for chaining an operation with promises *without* performing an async operation. For example:

```
fetch('./foo').then(x => x.json()).then(JSON.parse);
```

The last `JSON.parse` part has nothing to do with promises or async operations.

Comment: The last `then` will be parsing the Javascript object which is already parsed by `x.json()`?

Comment: `x.json()` returns the JSON string and `JSON.parse` parses the string? I guess it makes sense sometimes you return some value and make it a resolved promise. In your example can you make it `fetch('./foo').then(x => JSON.parse(x.json()))` ? Although, it is still returning a value without further chaining

Answer (score 0):

There are many cases of promise chains where the first promise handler returns a plain value but cannot be merged easily with the second promise handler in the chain:

- The intermediate promise is the return value of a function:

  ```
  function fn() {
    return myPromise.then(… => { …; return v1; });
  }
  fn().then(…)
  ```
- The first handler might also throw an exception besides returning a value, in which case the second one should not run but rather the rejection handler:

  ```
  myPromise.then(… => {
    if (…) throw new Error(…);
    else return v1;
  }).then(…, err => …);
  ```
- The first handler might also return a promise on other execution path, which needs to be awaited by the second handler:

  ```
  myPromise.then(… => {
    if (…) return fetchSomethingByPromise();
    else return v1;
  }).then(…);
  ```
- There is a rejection handler besides the first handler, whose result the second handler should also get:

  ```
  myPromise.then(… => v1, err => v2).then(…);
  ```

In all of these cases, the `then` function will need to deal with plain values. Sure, they always could have been wrapped in `Promise.resolve(v1)`, but it was decided not to require that. Also there's one more reason why `then` will need to deal with primitive values: a void handler (e.g. at the end of the chain) returns `undefined`, and `then` will need to handle that appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand more about promises to give some insight into this:

Whatever the fulfillment handler returns, primitive value, objects that are not thenables, thenables, real promises, this value will always resolve `p`, or made into a promise so that it resolves `p`, where `p` is what `.then()` returns.

This is called unwrapping in the promise community, I believe.

So if returning a primitive value or an objects that is not thenable:

this value will be used to resolve `p`, or it will be made into `Promise.resolve(v)` which is immediately resolved, and this is to resolve `p` immediately.

If it is an object that is a thenable, or a real promise:

it can be called as:

`obj.then(resolveP)`  where `resolveP` is the function that can resolve `p`.

then the thenable and real promise can both resolve `p`.

In the promise community, it seems even if it is primitive values or objects that are not thenable, will be made into a promise, so that future operations are more consistent: operation on a promise.

It doesn't matter if you wrap and wrap, because it will just unwrap and unwrap anyway. (when the inner promise resolves, it propagates the unwrapping to the outer wrap, until it cannot continue.)

It almost feels like as if promises are higher level objects that from now on, we only will work with them. (when we are dealing with promises and ordinary values, everything will be converted to a promise (by using `Promise.resolve(value)` and dealt with).